# Shouldn't this be out of scope?

Tags: python-3.x

Shouldn't line 5 error because y is not defined? to me it should be out of scope but still outputs with y=100. **Does python push the variable scope up a level? or is there a slow garbage collector? or some third thing?**

```
i = 0
for x in range(100):
    for y in range(100):
        i += y
    print(x, y)
```

Expected output:

> NameError: name 'y' is not defined

Actual output:

> 0 99
>
> 1 99
>
> 2 99
>
> 3 99
>
> 4 99
>
> 5 99...

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Python doesn't have block scope. And garbage collection wouldn't have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not be an error, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) explicitly call out the behaviour (paraphrased and emphasised below):

> `for_stmt ::= "for" target_list "in" expression_list ...`
>
> ***Names in the target list are not deleted when the loop is finished,*** but if the sequence is empty, they will not have been assigned to at all by the loop.